# Mpdf Automatic Page Break while using the correct padding

Tags: php, mpdf

### The Issue

I am using the Mpdf 8.0.0 library to generate dynamic content PDFs for document generation purposes. These PDFs have a sidebar that appears on the right, but only on the first page. The text flows down the left two thirds of the page until the page break, at which point the text should flow at full width for the remainder of the PDF.

I have successfully coded this first page sidebar, and the text flows nicely until it hits the second page, at which point the last paragraph from the first page that has been split continues with the same margin or padding on the second page, and then subsequent paragraphs correctly use the full width. This is shown in the image.

[image: Current Behaviour - last paragraph split onto second page uses first page margin/padding]

Ideally, however, I would prefer the text to flow down the second page being full width, as shown in this second image:

[image: Desired Behaviour - last paragraph split onto second page uses second page margin/padding]

---

### The Code

The way we have this arranged in mpdf is as such:

```
// After starting code to initialise mpdf, we add a page with increased margins on the right
// This allows for the text to flow down the left hand side
$mpdf->AddPageByArray([
  'margin-left' => 10,
  'margin-right' => 77,
]);

// We then put in the sidebar; this is absolute positioned as shown below
$mpdf->WriteHTML($sidebar);

// We then reset margins to initial setting, and let the auto page break take over
// We have no idea which paragraph will cause auto page break as the content in $html is dynamic
$mpdf->SetRightMargin(10);
$mpdf->DefrMargin = 10;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

The sidebar HTML is as follows; we absolute position it, set height to match page height (we know it as we're set to Portrait A4 always), and width to 33%:

```
<div class="bkgd-grey sidebar-row" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; height: 297mm; width: 33%; padding: 20px 15px; overflow: auto; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- HTML Content on Sidebar -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the left hand side is dynamic HTML, mainly paragraphs, occasionally images, etc.

---

### Final Thoughts and Query

Having investigated this, I have found Mpdf's [page on page breaks](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html) enlightening. It mentions different kinds of page breaks if you force page breaks, that of slicing and cloning, and mentions that the automatic page break can only slice. I think this is the root of the issue; I require cloning, but since I can't know which paragraph will cause the page break to be needed, I can't force it without either under or overcorrecting (and I would have to break mid paragraph sometimes to make it look natural).

So my questions are this.

Is cloning the way forward? It looks like it might be, since it wraps each part independently in the correct padding/border. If so, is there a way to get Mpdf's automatic page break to act in this manner, or is this something I'd need coded in to get Mpdf to behave? Or regardless, does anyone know a workaround to get this working as I desire? Thank you!